# read one java.util.arrayqueue from more than one thread

Tags: java

Question, more than one thread of a process program could read sequentially from one static java.util.arrayqueue? If three threads of a process program are running and three data object arrive into the arrayqueue, each thread will process one data object or just one thread will process all three data object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing the producer-consumer pattern.

A few points

- If you spawn three threads and they each loop, reading off the same queue then they will all try to consume the items on the queue. There's no guarantees on how many items each thread will consume. This depends entirely on the scheduler of the threads in the JVM (or at the OS level). Generally speaking though if a large number of similar items are added to the queue each thread will consume roughly the same amount of items.
- ArrayQueue is not a good choice for this use-case as it is not threadsafe. A better choice would be ConcurrentLinkedQueue or ConcurrentBlockingQueue

To answer your question directly, yes you can have multiple threads reading from the same queue, but please consider the above.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you want to use synchronized Threads to that each Threads reads 1 input.

To answer you question, the behaviour in this context cannot be determine. You should force the synchronisation of you threads to make sure that each thread is busy at all time and not only one.

Answer (score 0):

You really really want to use synchronization in this case or switch to a more suitable data structure.

From documentation of arrayqueue:
They are not thread-safe; in the absence of external synchronization, they do not support concurrent access by multiple threads

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the arrayqueue push/pop is thread-safe and that any signaling used does not restrict the number of running threads:

Depends on how many cores are available and how fast the threads can process the data.  If there are three free cores and the tasks queued take some time, the three threads may well run the three tasks concurrently.   If the tasks are trivially short and there is some load on the system such that only one thread is free at the time of data submission, the one thread might race round and execute all three items before another thread becomes avaialable.  If there are fewer cores than tasks, then obviously only [no. of cores] tasks may run concurrently.

Mix and match those possibilities.